# Add a 5x5 grid layout to a JComboBox using action listener?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, actionlistener

I have to display a dropdown menu that when New Game is selected, a 5x5 area is displayed on which the game I'm creating for a school project displays Location instances for a game of assassin. But I cannot get the grid to display when I select New game but the Jcombobox and action listener work to the best of my knowledge. How would I fix this and if there's any way to make it simpler and more efficient?

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class mainView {
private static JPanel newGame;
private static JFrame main;

protected static void newGamePanel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    GridLayout lay = new GridLayout(5,5);
    newGame = new JPanel();
    newGame.setLayout(lay);
    newGame.setVisible(true);
    newGame.setLocation(200, 300);
    newGame.setSize(200,200);
    main.add(newGame);

}

public static void codeNameView(){
    main = new JFrame("CodeNames");
    main.setSize(400, 600);
    main.setVisible(true);
    //dropdown menu for quit and new game
    String[] choice = {" " , "New Game" , "Quit"};
    final JComboBox<String> dropDown = new JComboBox<String>(choice);

    //below is the panel where we add new game and quit too
    JPanel dropDownPanel = new JPanel();
    dropDownPanel.add(dropDown);
    main.add(dropDownPanel);
    //ok button stuff


    //action listener for dropdown combobox
    dropDown.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      //functionality for combobox
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            Object selectedOption = dropDown.getSelectedItem();
           // Object command = e.getActionCommand();
            if (selectedOption == "Quit") {
                 main.dispose();    
            }else if(selectedOption == "New Game"){

                newGamePanel();

            }


                }


    });

}








public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            codeNameView();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use static variables and methods in your class. This indicates improper design.

> But I cannot get the grid to display when I select New game

When you add a component to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

You need the revalidate to invoke the layout manager so the components added to the panel are given a size/location. Otherwise the size of the components are (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

> action listener work to the best of my knowledge.

Or maybe the problem is your code is never executed. How do you verify this?

Did you add a System.out.println(...) statement to the listener to verify which piece of code is executed???

```
if (selectedOption == "Quit") {
     main.dispose();    
}else if(selectedOption == "New Game"){

    newGamePanel();

}
```

Don't use "==" for a String comparison.

To compare the value of the String use the equals(...) method:

```
if ("New Game".equals(selectedOption))
    //  do something
```

Edit:

> the string itself prints and the newGamePanel(); does not

Also, your code just continues to add components to the frame. Swing actually paints the last component added first. So if you add multiple game panels to the frame, the first one added will always be painted over top of the last panel added.

So a better solution is to use a `CardLayout` on the frame. This will allow you to swap panels so that only one is displayed at a time. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: I did add a system.out.println to the if statement and changed it so that it is  `if (selectedOption.equals("Quit")) {
         main.dispose(); 
       }else if(selectedOption.equals("NewGame")){
        
        newGamePanel();
        System.out.print("yolo");`

Comment: the string itself prints and the newGamePanel(); does not